# White screen popped up. All of sudden not able to do anything. Scam or something else?

Tags: malware, windows, privacy, vpn

I have been using this laptop for the last 6 months and never had any issue, but last Friday I was watching a movie and then all of sudden my PC restarted and a white screen (see figure below) showed up after reboot.

I tried a few things. I tried Task Manager and all but it didn't work out. 
I restarted the PC, but I couldn't do anything.

I reinstalled the windows again it again popped out,
later on, I formatted the whole laptop 
clean windows 10 installation + Format

After a day it showed up again and this time I'm not even able to login and after boot it's coming directly.

Things I noticed:
1: It's coming from **internet explorer**
2: I was able to locate the webpage directory it was *C/Pograndata/wcttempoff.html*

Screenshots attached. Last time when it showed up again after formatting the whole Drive I took out the hard drive from the laptop and then using a connector connected it to the PC and **deleted the files** from program Data linked to this message & IE But no Success

Hidding my IP or by using VPN can these things handle this? ( ss joined )
[image]

Comment: Hi Gaurav, How did you reinstall windows? Did you create a USB/ISO with the Windows Media Creation Tool? Did you do this from the infected machine?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like scamware if anything - who even is this illusive "*Corporate Security*"? It's trying to get you to dial a number where they'll try sell some service or have you manually install something else.

You mention you were watching a movie - was it on a streaming site? If so, they're rife with these sorts of popups. If this is the case, you'll see a  URL at the top of your screen that it's loading (some quick Googling shows this number cropping up on a lot of self-reported scam call websites).

There must be some element of peristence for this wee infection - Malwarebytes/Avast/any number of good, free AV solutions will be able to scan your registry for anything lying there. Would recommend you do this rather than reinstalling Windows.

Comment: The registry is not where you would find malware.